# Blender Viewport FPS Drops (Animation Playback) on New Laptop

Tags: animation, 3d-view, timeline, frame-rate

I'll be quick here. Recently I bought a new machine with much better specs than my 8 year old Laptop, however the problem I am facing is that when I Animate inside Blender, initially I get blazing fast playback speed and over 30 Fps but overtime fps start to drop the more I work on it, also making animating character difficult. I then close blender, and when I restart, things get back to normal with good speed. This is the only hack I found, shutting down and restarting blender after sometime (Painful yes). This wasn't happening on my old machine. Help would be appreciated, thanks!

My Specs of Laptop:

**Processor**: Core i5 11th Gen Processor
**I-GPU**: Intel Iris XE (Latest Driver)
**RAM**: 16 GB at 3200 MHz
**Hard Drive**: 1TB
**SSD**: 256 nVme m.2

Comment: Loss of GPU performance over time can often be due to the GPU throttling it's clock back because it is getting too hot.  If you have windows something like gpu-z can be used to see the clock rate of the gpu and the temperature.  If it's that, the temp will go up over repeated runs and the clock will slow down.

Comment: @brockmann Temperature should be fine, as this is a new machine and how much load can a single character put on the System? So, i don't think so. Secondly, as i mentioned, this didn't happen in my Old Laptop. I am also using a Video Reference inside blender, that slows down as well.

Comment: @MartyFouts This didn't happen in my old Laptop man, and this is just a single character and video reference. Yes I have GPU-Z, but i don't think it is that.

Comment: @Kam_Bautista the odds are 45/45 it's a driver bug that's causing memory leaks so the restart recovers the memory or the Iris driver is more aggressive about thermal throttling than older drivers so you're seeing unexpected throttling.  Doesn't cost anything to use GPU-Z either way

Comment: @MartyFouts Sure I'll use GPU-Z. Machine is way faster than the previous Laptop, and definitely it is New Technology. New Intel Processors / Chip are pretty energy efficient. I tried all Iris drivers, same issue but anyways. I have seen Other posts regarding FPS drops as well on new machines, I think one was even using 1080 GTX, with slow playback.

Comment: @MartyFouts Intel Uses it's Turbo Boost Technology, to increase performance if an app requires. Though it is Safe, but I wonder if that technology is coming into play. Temperature of CPU, really go up to 90 degree quickly when required, but also cools down quickly when not rendering in any app. Cheers!

Comment: @MartyFouts So my observation is, now that i have tested a few things, CPU is throttling, not GPU, so after a while, rig gets slow. Turbo Boost technology is on by Default, is it safe to disable it Marty? Thanks.